# How to take two columns of two TXT and create new TXT with the two columns?

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have two text files with only one column each.

I need to take the column from each of the text files and create a new text file with the two columns with tabs.

These columns have no relation (ID) but are in order with each other.

I could do that in Excel, but there are more than 200 thousand lines and not accepted.

How can I do it in Pentaho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take 2 text input steps, read both the files,
2. after that add 2 add constant step create same column with some value,make sure the value of the both constant values remains same.
3. use stream lookup/merge join and merge them with constant values.
4. generate the file.

Comment: I don't think that'll work. If you have a constant in each stream, then all rows will match all other rows and stream lookup will return the 1st result of  the lookup stream. It should be a counter, and the row number field from the text file input will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can read both files with Text file input, add "row number" in each stream, which gives you two streams of 2 fields each. Then you can Merge join both streams on Row number, and finally a Select fields step to clean up the output so that only the two relevant fields are kept. Then Text file output to write it.